# How to add and item to array only if it doesnt exist already using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have an array called myarray[]. How i can add item to myarray only if that item already doesn't exist in array ?

```
  myarray.push({ url: urlValue, filename: fileNameValue });
```

Edited: i tried following but i get double pushed data after 3th push:

```
if (files === undefined || files.length == 0)
        {

           myarray.push({ url: urlValue, filename: fileNameValue });

        }

    for(var g=0; g<myarray.length; g++){
            if(myarray[g].url == urlValue)
            {
              alert('already in array');
            }
            else
            {

                   myarray.push({ url: urlValue, filename: fileNameValue });

            }//end of else
           }//end of for loop
```

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs#includes

Comment: Test if that item is in the array before you push.

Comment: Thanks for replies. Can you see my edited post i check before inserting but i keep getting double data each time i insert data on my 3th push onward!